# WCF service throws "The type [...] was not expected. Use the XmlInclude [...]" even if XmlInclude is already being used

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service (started from code) that uses an object not defined in the service definition. Because of that I have to use the `[XmlInclude]` attribute to make WCF understand how to serialize it.
For some reason this doesn't work and WCF still complains (I found the exception using tracing) that I have to use `[XmlInclude]` for the type already defined.

What am I missing here?

### Code to start WCF service

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), "http://localhost/myservice");

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy12;

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
host.Open();
```

### Service implementation

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://services.mysite.com/MyService")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class MyService : WebService, IMyService {

    [WebMethod]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InnerObject))]
    public MyReturnObject Test() {
        return new MyReturnObject(new InnerObject());
    }
}
```

### Service definition / interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService {

    [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
    MyReturnObject Test();
}
```

### Return types

The `MyReturnObject` class contains a generic object that can contain whatever I want. For this example I include a `InnerObject` type as defined above, and the type definitions look like so.

```
[KnownType(typeof(InnerObject))]
public class MyReturnObject {
    public object Content { get; set; }

    public MyReturnObject(object content) {
        Content = content;
    }
}

public class InnerObject {
    public int Foo;
    public string Bar;
    // And some other properties
}
```

### Complete exception

> System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> The type InnerObject was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[ServiceKnownType]` on your wcf service

Comment: On which class? On `MyReturnObject`, `IMyService` or `MyService`

Comment: on sevice impl `MyService`

Comment: Adding it to `MyService` didn't work. I tried adding it to `IMyService` which kinda worked in that the exception no longer appeared, but the returned data is not a proper object. I'm using https://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/ to test the service. With `[ServiceKnownType]`on the interface I get the object as an array of XmlNodes instead of a proper object. If I specifically change `MyReturnObject` to directly reference `InnerObject` I get a proper object back and WebService Studio displays it as a proper object and not just an array of XmlNodes.

Comment: For some unknown reason everything suddenly started working (with `[ServiceKnownType]`). I have now removed `[KnownType]` from the return types and `[XmlInclude]` from the ServiceImplementation, and everything works just fine.